# What's faster, to hide/show an HTML element, or to delete/insert it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am developing a navbar where the selected button is marked by a triangle. Do I put a triangle in every button of my navbar and keep all but one triangle invisible (or visible but same background as the button)?  Or do I delete the triangle and reinsert it in the new button?

I understand the performance impact would probably be negligible, but I am learning my ropes, so mostly asking out of curiosity (and wanting to learn the best practices)

Comment: You could add a css class to the selected button and display the triangle with css (e.g. background-image)

Comment: Regarding performance: Only you can answer that, with objective benchmarks.  The rest of your question is quite opinion based, since there's no "right" answer to this.  Personally I'd probably go with a CSS class that adds the relevant stuff and apply it where necessary.

Comment: Usually delete causes hide and insert causes show.

Comment: Since this is just a little triangle, and not a sophisticated animation, you should not see a big difference in performance. But as said before, CSS gives you a more maintainable way to style your elements (just by adding/removing a class).

Comment: Measure it and find out.....??????#

Answer (score 1):

I would do this sort of thing with CSS. Create an "`active`" class, then add/remove the class with javascript. This is cleaner and will let you have more control over the styling of your chosen indicator (in this case, a triangle).

Answer (score 1):

```
.normal{
   //normal css for all tabs
}

.normal.active{
   //triangle CSS for active one
}
```

now on selection by using JS add `active` class on particular tab and remove from others.

Comment: Is the second dot a logical "and"?

Comment: @ТаняТ. yes it is.In CSS we do like this.

Comment: @ТаняТ. No, the dot is part of the CSS class selector `.active`. It's not a logical AND. What makes it do AND is the fact that both classnames are stuck together, with no space in the middle. `.normal .active` would select `.active` elements inside `.normal` elements. Stick them together, and you get elements that have both classes.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a space for your triangle on every menu item. It should just be set to visible on hover. Setting something from invisable to visable takes almost no time. Its better practice than deleting and loading images on a selection.

Comment: Thank you. (Though it's not hover, it's more like a sticky button)